# Matlab has critical error from clean install (possibly OS X related?)

Tags: java, macos, matlab, crash

Using R2014b on OS X Yosemite.

```
Exception in thread "Startup Class Loader" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.initialize(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Z
at jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.initialize(Native Method)
at jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.<clinit>(JVMUtil.java:58)
at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:179)
at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:83)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer.initializeJOGL(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:114)
at com.mathworks.hg.peer.JavaSceneServerPeer.<clinit>(JavaSceneServerPeer.java:100)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at com.mathworks.mde.desk.StartupClassLoader.loadClass(StartupClassLoader.java:258)
at com.mathworks.mde.desk.StartupClassLoader.access$900(StartupClassLoader.java:25)
at com.mathworks.mde.desk.StartupClassLoader$2.run(StartupClassLoader.java:244)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This pops up the moment I start matlab. I am unable to use imagesc() or imshow() and probably loads of other functions, because matlab crashes with `Caught unexpected exception of unknown type.` instantly.

I'm at my wits end. The matlab install is fresh, and so is the OS. Same problem using the Java from Apple or the Java from Oracle.

EDIT: Response from MathWorks is that integration with Maple breaks everything. Emptying the .maplerc.sh file in the /bin/ directory fixes everything.

Comment: This is pointing to a native library linking error. Do you have multiple jdk versions on your system?

Comment: @Kedamath I've tried using the Apple provided Java 6 only, the Oracle provided Java 8 only, and also having both installed.

Comment: Mathworks support is usually pretty good with such problems, they should be able to help you with this.

Comment: @hbaderts I'm a student and I'm not certain I qualify for technical support according to their disclaimer: "Students: Technical support from MathWorks is available for activation, installation, and bug-related issues only. For additional help visit our student resource page or contact your instructor." EDIT: Added a support ticket, they'll report back within a day it says.

Comment: If you were able to solve this yourself, feel free to answer (and even accept) your own question. This way you can provide a few more details than in your edited question in order to help any others with this.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by having installed Matlab integration through maple. A file called .maplerc.sh is placed within the /bin/ folder in the matlab .app, and it apparently breaks everything. You cannot delete the file (this causes matlab to not launch on start up) but you can erase its contents. This will create an error upon launch, but you can ignore it and everything will work fine.
Uninstall matlab and maple, and reinstall maple and matlab without integration will fix the issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace the contents of the file `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/.maplerc.sh` by an empty line (as suggested by the other answer from Dorako), and
2. Modify the file `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/toolbox/local/matlabrc.m`, by searching for `Maple` in this text file and comment-out or remove the part between the two lines containing `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`.

The second step ensures that there is no error or warning message any more on startup, so that re-installing the programs is not necessary.